# Count number of cells with cell background color Excel

Tags: excel

Beneath, you'll see the layout of an employee's weekly schedule:

[image]

I have used `=COUNTIF(B73:T73, "<>") / 3` to calculate the number of days worked per week on the third column to the right.

The cells formatted to yellow represent working in the office (WFO) whereas the ones formatted in brown represent working from home (WFH). I'm looking to produce a formula which will count the number of days worked from home and from the office based on cell background color. I have researched and can't seem to find a solution.

Is this achievable? Or is there an alternative way to do this without manually filling in the numbers?

Comment: VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx

Comment: Would prefer to do it solely using Excel if possible

Comment: If you meant just Excel formulas ... not possible. First sentence under "Introduction" in the link: "Excel provides essentially no support in worksheet functions for working with cell colors."

Comment: Are the colors set with conditional formatting or manually?